# Colocar dados de formulário em Array

Tags: php, mysql

Seguinte galera, tenho um banco de dados com alguns itens e exibo os itens desse banco de dados usando esse modelo:

```
<?php $conexao = mysqli_connect("Host","User","Pass","banco");
        if( !$conexao ){
            echo "Erooooou.";
            exit;
        }

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM produtos ORDER BY id DESC";
        $consulta = mysqli_query($conexao, $sql);
        if( !$consulta ){
            echo "Erro ao realizar consulta. Tente outra vez.";
            exit;
        }


        while( $dados = mysqli_fetch_assoc($consulta) ){

            $imagem  = $dados['imagem'];

            echo "<div class='shop1'>";
            echo "<img src='$imagem'>";
            echo "<div><p>" .$dados['nome']. "</p></div>";
            echo "<div><p>" .$dados['valor']. "</p></div>";
            echo "<input type='number' name'quantidade'>";
            echo "</div>";      }?>
```

Esse código ta pegando todos os dados do meu banco e exibindo, cada um em uma div bonitinho, ate então tudo beleza, negocio é que eu queria pegar os valores digitados naquele input e enviar para uma próxima página, de maneira que eu possa manipula-los, e guardar de novo em outro Banco de dados, exemplo:

> Pegar todos os dados digitados no INPUT de todos os itens exibidos, junto com a ID do usuário que está na $_SESSION e guarda-los em um outro banco de dados de Logs, para quando na página de Logs do usuário exiba a quantidade de cada item que ele requisitou.

É possível isso em PHP?
Como faria isso?
E me desculpem galera, eu estou aprendendo ainda, tenham paciência comigo!

Comment: Você pode usar o `$_SESSION` ou passar pela URL com `GET` `seusite.com?a=teste&b=teste2...`

Answer (score 0):

Você pode coloca-los em uma $_SESSION, exemplo:

```
$_SESSION['nome'] = $dados['nome'];
$_SESSION['nome'] = $dados['valor'];
```

e resgata-los na outra página, depois no final da página limpar a session...

```
unset($_SESSION[...]);
```

você pode também colocar um input `type = hidden` e definir o value com `<?php echo $dados['nome']; ?>` e fazer um `$_POST` na página seguinte pra pegar o conteúdo.

Espero ter ajudado de alguma forma, qualquer coisa to aqui.

Comment: Não é tão simples assim, seria se fosse só um item, mas a quantidade de itens na página vai ser relativo a quantidade de itens salvo no banco de dados.

Comment: Você pode criar uma array em $_SESSION...

Answer (score 0):

consegui a resposta, depois de analisar a resposta do $ProgramadorCaio, percebi que dava pra ser feio usando Array, e depois de estudar um pouco descobri que pra enviar os dados do input era simplesmente coloca-los com mesmo `NAME` mas como se fosse um vetor, exemplo:

```
echo "<input type='number' name='quantidade[]'>";
```

Desse modo, ao formulário ser enviado na outra página ele é recebido como Array, depois disso eu decidi gravar os dados em uma banco de dados, assim ficou fácil manipula-lo com facilidade.
Obrigado aos que responderam!